# Exclude @Configuration from Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have bunch of modules (say 3). Two are Spring boot based module and another one is Spring based.
Say Module 1 - SpringBoot
    Module 2 - Spring Boot
    Module 3 - Common Module only Spring based

Module 3 @Configuration file defined which needs to be picked only by Module 2 and not 1.

I tried bunch of things to exclude the configuration file. For ex:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.adobe"}
, excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {WorkerConfig.class, WorkerExecutors.class, Worker.class})})
public class Application {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

But Still the @Configiration Class is not getting excluded and Spring is trying to load it in application context which I dont want. My config class

```
@Configuration
public class WorkerConfig {

  @Bean
  public WorkerExecutors workerExec() {
    WorkerExecutors executors = new WorkerExecutors();
    return executors;
  }

}
```

Also I do read in @ComponentScan annotation that

```
 * <p>Note that the {@code <context:component-scan>} element has an
 * {@code annotation-config} attribute; however, this annotation does not. This is because
 * in almost all cases when using {@code @ComponentScan}, default annotation config
 * processing (e.g. processing {@code @Autowired} and friends) is assumed. Furthermore,
 * when using {@link AnnotationConfigApplicationContext}, annotation config processors are
 * always registered, meaning that any attempt to disable them at the
 * {@code @ComponentScan} level would be ignored.
```

So looks like excluding in Component Scan wont work.  Other than above, I also tried excluding using

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {WorkerExecutors.class, Worker.class,WorkerConfig.class})
public class Application {
```

But spring boot throws

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
    - com.adobe.repository.worker.lib.config.WorkerConfig
    - com.adobe.acp.repository.worker.lib.core.WorkerExecutors
    - com.adobe.acp.repository.worker.lib.core.Worker
```

Any idea how can I disable component scanning a non spring boot module in  a spring boot module other than putting in a different package. I dont want to put in different package.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: A somewhat hacky way to do this would be to provide the `Worker` configurations with the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation and then set the property only for module 2.

Comment: Yeah this works..I used conditional and not condition by property as it brings in spring boot dependency which I wanted to avoid..but y u say it's hacky?

Comment: It's kind of hacky because - as mentioned in some of the other comments, you would ideally split up your modules so that only the code that is required to be on the classpath is actually on the classpath (i.e. module 1 should not even be able to access the unwanted configuration classes of module 3). By using "piece-wise" component scanning like this, you may encounter bugs/issues down the road where something from a Worker *does* need to be present in Module 1 after all and force you to rework this approach. But if it works for you and you can deal with these issues, it's also a way to go.

Comment: Agree to this. But for now its one off classes so does not make lot of sense to move them out of classpath. But yes, when things like these increase, definitely the code can become buggy and difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 28):

You can try this it works for me:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters  = {@ComponentScan.Filter(
              type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {WorkerConfig.class, WorkerExecutors.class, Worker.class})})
```

Comment: Actually it wont.

Comment: I found that this only worked if I specified a `basePackages` property on the `@ComponentScan` annotation.

Answer (score 8):

Auto-config packages lives under org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure. That's the reason why you can't do:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {WorkerExecutors.class, Worker.class,WorkerConfig.class})
```

Spring does what you tell to do. You are calling:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.adobe"}
, excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {WorkerConfig.class, WorkerExecutors.class, Worker.class})})
```

Therefore Spring won't load any of those Worker classes. That's why Spring doesn't "execute" your classes annotated with @Configuration.

That said, what you are trying to do doesn't make sense to me. Sounds like you have "modules" (java classes), but all of them are part of the same spring context. If you have a single Spring Context, then you can tell Spring to load some @Configuration classes and not some others. Then, from your "modules", you can inject whatever you need. Module 1 will inject Beans from Module 3, but Module 2 won't. Simple as that.

If for some reason you really need to prevent Module 2 accessing to beans from Module 3, but still keep Module 3 visible from Module 1, then I would separate Module 1 and Module 2 in two different Spring Boot Apps, and Module 3 becomes common code. But this approach may break your current architecture.

**UPDATE ON Fri Mar 29 2019**

Try this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myapp" }, excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = { MyClass2.class }) })
```

It worked for me. I have MyClass and MyClass2, and MyClass is loaded and MyClass2 is not. I tried it with Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE and Spring Bom for all the dependencies.

Comment: Spring is loading Worker classes, that's the issue. I want it not to load them but the current code doesnt work.
Also, think I was not elaborate in my question. 

Module 1 and Module 2 are seperate Spring boot Apps and Module 3 is a common code. This is where my worker Classes are (including config). They want to be loaded by Module 2 and other modules but not Module 1 , but some other config classes present in Module 3 are required by Module 1. Of course I can seperate Module 3 into Module 4 as well where Module 1 never scans 4 but I am looking how to do in current code structure i mention

Comment: Well, if Module 3 has code that is needed in Module 2 but not in Module 1, then Module 3 is really common code. I know you know this, just pointing the problem out. Now, from my experience, using @Configuration in common code is not that good, because it will scan by all the sub projects (or modules or whatever you want to call it). What has helped me a lot, is to put the code in a common place, but not the Spring annotations, just the code. Let's say you have Module 3 with a bunch of Java code, but without Spring annotations. Keep reading next comment ->

Comment: Then, if Module 2 needs the code from Module 3, then you need to create a Configuration class in Module 2 that creates all the @Beans using the types/code from Module 3. Makes sense? That is the way to go.

Comment: Sounds fair . But only thing is module 3 will be called not only by module 2 but more modules (4,5 ) so on..so we will end up duplicating code in all the modules..which is what I want to avoid..

Comment: Well, it not actually duplicating code. Quick example: I used to work in a project which had like 10 springboot apps. All of them were configured to used an API Key Filter bean. So, the logic for API key filtering was placed in a class called APIKeyFilter, inside a common java module. Then, each Spring Boot app would create a bean like this:

@Bean
public APIKeyFilter apikeyfilter(){}

Answer (score 0):

Same situation as the following doesn't work for me either:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myapp" }, excludeFilters = { 
@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = { MyClass2.class }) })
```

I managed to fix it in a not-so-proper manner by putting `@ConditionalOn...` on the configuration of module 3 itself and defining the condition through modules 1 and 2. (I did it with a Bean defined in module 1)

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(Module1ClassExample.class)
public class WorkerConfig {
```

The downside is that module 3 has to be aware of other potential modules, thus, increasing the coupling...